# How to stop AWS EKS Worker Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, cluster-computing, amazon-eks

I wonder if that would be possible to temporary stop the worker VM instances so they are not running at night time when I am not working on a cluster development. So far the only way I am aware of to "stop" the instances from running is to delete the cluster itself which I don't want to do. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

#### P.S. Edited later

The cluster was created following steps outlined in [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-console.html) guide.

Comment: How did you create your EKS worker nodes? Have you used the Cloud Formation template provided by [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/launch-workers.html) guide?  If so, I think you can just update your Cloud Formation config and set _NodeAutoScalingGroupDesiredCapacity_ to _0 (zero)_.

Comment: I created cluster by following the steps outlined in this guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-console.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to **EC2 instances dashboard** of your Node Group and from right panel in bottom click on **Auto Scaling Groups** then select your group by click on checkbox and click edit button and change Desired, Min & Max capacities to 0

[image: Auto Scaling groups -> Group size]

Comment: This seems to be not possible anymore... The message from AWS Dashboard says: "The minimum allowed size for maximum number of nodes is 1."

Comment: I change all the capacities above to 0. It turned out all of my worker nodes was Terminated.  @Fisal

Answer (score 17):

I'm just learning myself but this might help. If you have [eksctl](https://eksctl.io/) installed, you can use it from the command line to scale your cluster. I scale mine down to the min size when I'm not using it:

```
eksctl get cluster
eksctl get nodegroup --cluster CLUSTERNAME
eksctl scale nodegroup --cluster CLUSTERNAME --name NODEGROUPNAME --nodes NEWSIZE
```

To completely scale down the nodes to zero use this (max=0 threw errors):

`eksctl scale nodegroup --cluster CLUSTERNAME --name NODEGROUPNAME --nodes 0 --nodes-max 1 --nodes-min 0`

Answer (score 5):

Edit the autoscaling group and set the instances to 0.
This will shut down all worker nodes.
Now you can use AWS Automation to schedule a repetitive action through automation documents that will be stopping/starting at given periods of time.
You can't stop the master nodes as they are managed by AWS.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [kube-downscaler](https://github.com/hjacobs/kube-downscaler) which can be deployed to cluster to scale in and out the deployments based on time of day.

More cost reduction techniques in [this blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/cost-optimization-for-kubernetes-on-aws/).