# Nodegroup with nodes in EKS

Tags: amazon-eks, kubectl

I am trying to get nodegroups assigned to each of the nodes in EKS, but not able to find any command with eksctl or kubectl to get that done.
I have tried: eksctl list-nodegroups, describe-nodegroups but none of them give me the nodes along with nodegroups. Nowhere in doc I find how we can do that.
Is thr any way we can get this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69982072/unable-to-get-nodegroup-info-using-eskctl?rq=2

Comment: No..i just want to list my nodes with nodegroups..either with eksctl or kubectl using some jq or any other method..

Answer (score 2):

> ... want to list my nodes with nodegroups..either with eksctl or kubectl using some jq

This command will provide you the list of nodes and node group.

`kubectl get nodes -o json | jq -r '.items[] | [.metadata.name, .metadata.labels."eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup"] | @tsv' | column -t -s $'\t'`